# How to 'remove' an Object from a Java array (can't use Collections)

Tags: java, arrays

As a sample, I am developing a simple MySortedSet in java which implements SortedSet interface. It is backed up with a simple array which is E[] array.

I have several questions regarding that:

This is the class: (I am not writing entire code, instead of related parts)

```
public class MySortedSet<E> implements SortedSet<E>, Iterator<E> {

 private E[] array;
 private Comparator<? super E> _comparator;
 private int size = 0;
 private int capacity;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public MySortedSet() {
    this.capacity = 10;
    this.array = (E[]) new Object[this.capacity];
    // this.array = Array.newInstance(Class<E> var,int size);
    // We have to get Class<E> from outside caller.
 }
}
```

Since it accepts all sort of type from primitive to reference types etc. I am not really sure when removing an item, assigning null is a good way in place of the removed item. Since Java initializes primitive types with 0. So null only works for reference types.

Below is probably very bad design:

```
@Override
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    int indexOfElement = this.find(o);
    boolean removed = false;
    if (indexOfElement != -1) {
        this.array[indexOfElement] = null;
        removed = true;
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Can someone tell me what the best way is to remove an element from an array?

**Edit:**

Honestly what I am thinking to remove an element from an simple array is like copy the entire array without the removed item into a whole new array but I am not sure how efficient it would be in terms of performance and etc.

Comment: This isn't just about removing an element from an array. You're trying to implement `remove` for a `SortedSet` implementation backed by an array. I think it'll help the question if you make that clear in the title.

Comment: This implementation does not accept primitive types as far as I can see.

Comment: @Perception: I believe it accepts primitive types in place of E. Why would you say that?

Comment: @Braveyard - autoboxing allows you to store primitive types in an object array, as their object equivalents. But your still not actually storing primitive types.

Comment: @Braveyard in regards to performance, using `System.arraycopy()` to create a new array is pretty good - I use it relatively frequently and I've never had performance problems. I believe this method is also used for some of the Collections anyway, such as LinkedList (I think its LinkedList?)

Comment: @WATTOStudios - 1) you are thinking of ArrayList.  2) The cost of copying an array is `O(N)`, but the cost of adding an element to a List can be `O(1)`, depending on where you add the element.

Comment: Thanks yes, I was thinking of ArrayList. Depending on the use of this, an `O(n)` might not be too bad, but it will depend on the context - wouldn't be the best for exponentially large arrays, or doing it often. Agree that Lists would be better, if the user were allowed to use Collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It kinda depends on the context of how you want to use your array. For example, if you are going to be iterating over the array and using the contents of it for standard methods like `Arrays.sort()`, they might generate `NullPointerExceptions` if you have `null` values in your array.

If you really want to remove items from an array in a safe way, I'd suggest changing your array to an `ArrayList` like this...

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
list.add(object);
list.remove(object);
```

As this will actually remove the item from the list completely - no `nulls` or anything will remain, and performing methods like `length()` will return a real value.

For instances when I have used an array, I set the value to `null`, and ensure that all iterations over the array check that `value != null` before I try to query it. After setting the `nulls` for the removed items, I usually loop over the array and manually sort all the `nulls` to the end of the array, and then do `System.arraycopy()` to resize the array. This will leave you with a new array of the correct size, with all items in it except for the removed ones. However, I suggest this only if you really must use an array, as it is slower and introduces much greater potential for errors and `NullPointerExceptions`.

Alternatively, if you're not worried about sort-order, you can simple move the last item in the array over the top of the item you want to remove, and keep a count of the *real* array size. For example...

```
Object[] array = new Object[20];
int realSize = 15; // real number of items in the array

public void remove(int arrayIndex){
    array[arrayIndex] = array[realSize-1];
    realSize--;
}
```

This method removes an item in the array by 'replacing' it with the item in the last position of the array - its very quick and pretty to implement, if you don't care about sort order.

Comment: What about primitive types as they are initialized to 0 for numbers?

Comment: P.S: It must be a simple array as back-up. I cannot use an Collections since I am not allowed to.

Comment: I would suggest that all primitives should use an Object-equivalent array, such as `Integer[]` or `Long[]` - that way you could include `nulls`. Seeing as though you must use arrays, I would suggest my second-half of the answer, particularly around sorting and `System.arraycopy()`.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get primitive types in here; at most their wrappers.